# Long image names breaking CSS divs

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have grid posts on the home page of the site. These posts get uploaded by users and they have information all over the place. From long posts titles (now limited to 50) to long image names.

When an image name is too long, it breaks the HTML code, breaks the classes, divs, etc and results in the grid post to show in a "weird" way when rendered in Chrome and Firefox. Below are screen shots of the correct and broken formats.

[Correct Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oq1SC.png)

[Broken Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qR7Jq.png)

This is how the HTML code looks when the format is correct:

```
<div class="grid-image-holder">
            <img onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://image_URL_replaced/nopic.png';" title="This is the Post Title for SEO" alt="Same as post title" src="//cache-DOMAIN.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/images-160x130.png" class="attachment-160x130" height="130" width="160">

                </div>
                <div class="grid-padd"> etc...
```

And this is how the HTML looks when the code is broken (image name is too long):

```
<div class="grid-image-holder">
            <img onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://image_URL_replaced/nopic.png';" title="This is the Post Title for SEO" alt="Same as post title" src="//cache-DOMAIN.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/microsoft_aaa_02675_microsoft_office_home_business_2013_9840841-130x130.jpg" class="attachment-160x130" grid-padd"="" height="130" width="130">
```

Notice how the `<div class="grid-padd">` is now broken, missing the `height="130" width="160"></div><div class="` and only continueing into the next broken `div`.

I know this can be fixed by limiting/renaming the image name on upload, but surely there's something no right here. Why would this happen, and is there a proper solution instead of hacking a quick solution for it?

Appreciate any help.

P.S: This problem started when we added this `onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='https://image_URL_replaced/nopic.png';"` to replace 404 images with a default image on the site as CDNs are not 100% reliable.

Comment: `img` tag should be self-closed, as `<img src="" />`.

Comment: thanks, but this didn't fix it. Issue is still there.

Comment: Recheck your code and rethink your flow, trust that long image name has nothing to do with your bug, at least the length does, find another way.

Comment: Found the issue/fix. find answer below. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Problem solved.

We have a table in the DB to store `image_url_cache` which stores the whole img tag information to make the load time faster for images. The column size it limited to **512 characters**. When the img tag is greater than 512 characters it's breaking the HTML as only the first 512 characters are getting stored in the DB.

Fix: increase the column size for **1024 characters** fixed the issue.